# Request ambiguos between the following action methods Create

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have looked at the solutions on the site. i have created two methods one for [HttpPost] and another for [HttpGet] as shown but still i am getting that error message. The code is as shown. but when i make a post request to the server i still get the error.

```
     [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }



    [HttpPost]
    public String Create(Customer Customer)
    {
     /// logic here 
      return "Done";
    }
```

The current request for action 'Create' on controller type '******Controller' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
System.String Create(Data.Models.***) on type Data.Controllers.UserController
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Create(System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection) on type Data.Controllers.UserController i am calling the method from a javascript code as shown below that is when I get the error message.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: urlPath + '/Create',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: ko.toJSON(this),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (result) {
            window.location.href = urlPath + '/';
        }
```

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak I would hazzard a guess that this is a runtime error, not a compile one.

Comment: Can you share the code that calls the action?

Comment: I am using ajax call to the server to send the data. you can see the code from above. well that is what i thought but when the script makes a call that is the response i am getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your error message. These methods are OK as they are. But you have another `Create` method with `FormCollection` parameter: `Create(System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection)`. If you don't have that method anymore, maybe you forgot to build your project?

Comment: I have built the project and i have only the two creates as shown but i am making an AJAX call to the server as shown above. it puzzles me too it should work.

Comment: sawa the problem there was another method Create(System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection) i couldnt see it. thanks.